# Collection View cell overlapping

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uicollectionview

I am using collection view in my app.

Here is the code.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",indexPath.row+1]];

    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    lbl.text = [arrCategory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```

But when i run the code i get like this.The cell are overlapping.

[image]

I dont know why it is like that. Also some time it show me more margin between two rows.

All images are static.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you return the correct height for those cells?

Comment: You say that the images are static. Does that mean you have disabled scrolling for the UICollectionView? In other words are you wanting all of your images to appear on screen without needing to scroll, or is this problem there when in reality you should be able to scroll down to see more?

Comment: No i have not disable scrolling and i dont want images to show with out scrollig. And no i have not return height for that cells.

Comment: @Eiko Which method to use for specifing height for cells?

Comment: @Impossible Look into UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol, there's itemSize, and there's collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:. If using interface builder / storyboards, there is probably a way to set it, too (or will get set automatically).

Comment: Yes i have set it but stil there is a issue.